# How to extract ethereum from the smart contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am a newbie in the blockchain technology and I have question.
I just deployed an Ethereum smart contract to the Rinkeby testnet network and minted a few NFTs. When checking my contract address on rinkeby.etherscan.io I can see the smart contract's balance.

The question is, how can I transfer these ethereum in the smart contract balance to my wallet. Since I am the owner I should receive these ETH somehow to my metamask wallet no?

Smart contract includes the following function

````
    // This will transfer the remaining contract balance to the owner.
    // Do not remove this otherwise you will not be able to withdraw the funds.
    (bool os, ) = payable(owner()).call{value: address(this).balance}('');
    require(os);
  }```

so it should be possible...
````

Comment: Can you share the contract address on Rinkeby (assuming it's verified on a blockchain explorer) or its full source code? The snippet you provided might or might not be reachable depending on other context.

Comment: @PetrHejda
This is the contract address (0xB2BEd94F323DB2a6825FE29756e7aFcadd076eb9) and it is verified rinkeby.etherscan

Answer (score 1):

Per your current implementation, you need to manually invoke the `withdraw()` function from the `owner` address each time you want to withdraw ETH from the contract.

Your mint functions accept ETH and keep it on the contract address.

If you want to transfer the funds to the `owner` each time a mint is performed, you need to explicitly invoke the transfer from each of the mint functions. Example:

```
function mint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable mintCompliance(_mintAmount) mintPriceCompliance(_mintAmount) {
    require(!paused, 'The contract is paused!');

    _safeMint(_msgSender(), _mintAmount);

   // auto transfer received funds to the owner
   payable(owner()).transfer(msg.value);
}
```

Comment: Adding this line in the contract will result in gas fees on every mint (since eth is transferred to my wallet) or it is free?

Comment: @JadKev this will result in a gas fee after each mint, but this would be something that ```msg.sender``` would end up paying. So it would essentially add 21,000 gas to what's already calculated in your mint method.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to withdraw the funds from your contract to a wallet you own you must implement a `withdraw` method like so:

```
 address public primary_wallet = YOUR_WALLET_ADDRESS
 
 function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
   (bool os,)= payable(primary_wallet).call{value:address(this).balance}("");
   require(os);
 }
```

You will also need to make sure that you import `import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";` to use the `onlyOwner` modifier.  This allows only the person who deployed the contract to withdraw the funds and nobody else. This is a must.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already have this function implemented:
function withdraw() public onlyOwner nonReentrant {
    (bool os, ) = payable(owner()).call{value: address(this).balance}('');
    require(os);
  }

I can see on rinkeby.etherscan my contract balance but I should be able to transfer this amount in the contract to my wallet. In other words, shouldn't the balance in my wallet be increasing on each mint? Since I am the owner.

Comment: @JadKev no, the withdraw method does not get called on every mint.  You can either do this manually by going to etherscan and calling this method in the ```write``` section of the contract, or by calling it inside your mint method at the end of the function.  Only then will you receive the balance that is stored in your smart contract.

Comment: I get the following error while trying to write "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'methods')"

Comment: @JadKev how are you trying to call the withdraw method??

Comment: I connected to web3 on etherscan and tried to call it. Am I missing something? I am really new to this :) thanks for your patience...

Comment: I minted more NFTs until the contract balance is above 0.1 and it worked. I can see the ETH in my wallet as well as the transaction!! There is a certain amount for the balance to be able to withdraw it?

Comment: @JadKev please add a link to your contract so that I can better assist you. From what I know I don't believe there is a limit as to how much eth is needed before withdrawing from your contract.

Comment: Here it is 0xB2BEd94F323DB2a6825FE29756e7aFcadd076eb9

Comment: @JadKev try adding the ```payable``` keyword to your ```withdraw``` method and see what happens.

Comment: I did, this is the new contract 0xcB25eA002e8C21Ec4B28A478bDa3ee5417D18329 (i have to deploy again if I wanna make a change right?). I tried minting but the ETH went to the previous contract.

Comment: @JadKev if you are deploying your contract using hardhat or truffle, you need to make sure that you update the contract abi of the new contract address, otherwise it will still be using the old contract methods

Comment: How do I update the abi?

Comment: @JadKev let's continue this discussion elsewhere.  You can message me on my personal twitter account @_syndk8